# Auto Incremented Name Attribute on Radio Buttons

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that has a set of radio buttons, and I am sending the value of the checked button to another page with php. The form has the option to add another set of the same radio buttons, so if I use the following method of giving name attributes:

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="food[]" value="apple" /> Apple
    <input type="radio" name="food[]" value="orange" /> Orange
</div>
```

And add a clone of the above,

```
$_POST['food'];
```

This would give me the value of each input, and that would total 4. I'm trying to use the bracket incrementing method but still keep the functionality of returning the value of the radio button that was checked.

So my question is, is there a way to use the square brackets to do auto incrementing on the name attribute, but when sending the values to php make sure each div grouping of radio buttons only returns one of the values for whichever one is checked? Please let me know if this question is too vague, this is my first question here.

Comment: Can you show a sample of what you are expecting to get as a result? Your question is very vague...can't really tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you sure you got EVERY radio input with `food[]`? I made a simple test on localhost and PHP only receives the selected one (though in array form), i.e. If I selected "Orange", PHP only receives `$_POST["food"][0]="orange"`, no "Apple".

Answer (score 0):

May i don't understand your question. You can not Auto Incremented the name cause you use radio buttons. By Choosing apple on the first page and orange on the second you will loose your first choose (apple). You can do it with checkboxes instead of radio buttons:

Page 1:

```
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="numberofapples" value="1" /> Apple
    <input type="checkbox" name="numberoforanges" value="1" /> Orange
</div>
<input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

Page 2:

```
<form method="post" action="result.php">
<div>
    <?if($_POST['numberofapples']){?><input type="hidden" name="numberofapples" value="1" /> <?}?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="numberofapples" value="<?=($_POST['numberofapples'])?2:1?>" /> Apple
    <?if($_POST['numberoforanges']){?><input type="hidden" name="numberoforanges" value="1" /> <?}?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="numberoforanges" value="<?=($_POST['numberoforanges'])?2:1?>" /> Orange
</div>
<input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

Result page:

```
Apples: <?=($_POST['numberofapples'])?$_POST['numberofapples']:0?>
Oranges: <?=($_POST['numberoforanges'])?$_POST['numberoforanges']:0?>
```

But why don't you do the counting after posting your second page? (add the post values from page 1 as hidden fields to the form of page 2)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use several div groups with the same input names, I would create them like this:

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="food[0][]" value="apple" /> Apple
    <input type="radio" name="food[0][]" value="orange" /> Orange
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="food[1][]" value="apple" /> Apple
    <input type="radio" name="food[1][]" value="orange" /> Orange
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="food[2][]" value="apple" /> Apple
    <input type="radio" name="food[2][]" value="orange" /> Orange
</div>
```

So, in your PHP, you will have each group in separated keys. For example

```
print_r( $_POST['food'] );
```

Should return something like this:

```
array(
  [0] => array(
    [0] => 'apple'
  ),
  [1] => array(
    [0] => 'orange'
  ), 
  [2] => array(
    [0] => 'apple',
    [1] => 'orange'
  )
)
```

)

Comment: This is close to what I was referring to, so I am dynamically adding more divs that contain the radio buttons with jquery using the following, keeping in mind that I am manually through this code incrementing the first value (I clone the last div, find the radio buttons and get the name attribute and use a function to change it, the function includes this):
`var theNumber = $(this).attr('name').match(/^\d+$/);    
theNumber = +theNumber + 1;    
var a = $(this).attr('name').replace(/\d+/, theNumber);    
return a;
`
I can only increment from 0 to 1, after I add more divs, I still get `food[1]`

Comment: This is what I mean, check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ambM7/). If I add at least 3 new divs, and check the name attribute for the added divs, I can't increment past 1. I want to be able to keep incrementing past 1

Comment: They're all 1 because `newNum` is null. Also, remember to use `name[][]` instead of `name[]`.

Comment: This works great, thanks so much! Why though should I use two sets of brackets? If I have a set of radio buttons that both have `name[0]` for example, if I did `$_POST['food'][0]`, would I not receive the checked button?

Comment: Yes, but you wouldn't receive multiple selections if you work with only one set of brackets. It would make sense if the inputs were checkboxes instead of radios.